# Power BI Query Editor: list of column names containing a certain string

Tags: powerbi

> = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Average Revenue", each List.Sum({[#"nx1671 - AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"nx1670 -
>   AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"nx1669 - AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"hill2 -
>   AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"hill1 - AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"e784028 -
>   AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"e784027 - AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"e784026 -
>   AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"oakd02 - AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"oakd01 -
>   AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"sthl2 - AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"sthl1 -
>   AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"e782388 - AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"e782387 -
>   AvgRevenueTotal"],[#"e782386 - AvgRevenueTotal"]}),type number)

I am trying to make this code more dynamic. Currently when I add new files to the folder from which the data is being imported from I have to manually input the new columns names into the list above.

My question, is there a way I can search through and list all the column names in the table containing "AvgRevenueTotal"?

Perhaps creating a function as below:

> = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Average Revenue", each List.Sum(**ListColumnNames(**#"Filtered Rows1"**)**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is fairly easy to solve in the Query Editor, without complex code.

I would select all the columns besides your AvgRevenueTotal ones, then right-click and choose **Unpivot other columns**.  This will line up all the amounts in a new [Value] column, on multiple rows.  I would change the type of that column to a Decimal Number.

Finally I would then select the same columns as above and click **Group By**, then add an Aggregation to Sum the Value column, named "Average Revenue".

Comment: This includes all new columns added. Not, only the columns containing "AvgRevenueTotal".

The other columns added contain "AvgOutputTotal", "CntrRevenueTotal" and "CntrOutputTotal". These will subsequently need to be summed together in their own Total columns.

Comment: In that case I would stop this Query after the Unpivot, and start a new one for each of the Total columns, by Reference to this "Base" query.  In each Total column Query, I would Filter the Attribute column to get only the required values before using the Group By with Sum.  Finally I would stitch the 3 "Total column" Queries together using Merge and Expand.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use **Table.ColumnNames** function

Comment: I don't want all the columns, only those containing 'AvgRevenueTotal'